# Estimate color distribution with Gaussian mixture model

Tags: c++, opencv, background-color, video-capture, gaussian

I am trying to use two Gaussian mixtures with EM algorithm to estimate color distribution of a video frame. For that, I want to use two separate peaks in the color distribution as the two Gaussian means to facilitate the EM calculation. I have several difficulties with the implementation of these in OpenCV.

**My first question is:** how can I determine the two peaks? I've searched about peak estimation in OpenCV, but still couldn't find any seperate function. So I am going to determine two regions, then find their maximum values as peaks. Is this way correct?

**My second question is:** how to perform Gaussian mixture model with EM in OpenCV? As far as I know, the "cv::EM::predict" function could give me the index of the most probable mixture component. But I have difficulties with training EM. I've searched and found some other codes, but finding the correct parameters is too much difficult for. Could someone provide me any example code for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. When you said 'two peaks', did you refer to the peaks of Gaussian distribution? If so, you can easily get this value by computing the centre of the peak through the pdf, if it is available.
2. For your second question, actually, Opencv has documented an sample which may do the similar thing that you are trying to do. "Clustering random samples of multi-Gaussian distribution using EM"
It comes with the opencv document!!! http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/expectation-maximization.html

Comment: @james: I am using openCV 2.4.2, and after using that example code from opencv document, "CvEMParams" is not recognized. I've searched, and used "cv::EM""paramType" instead, but still it is incorrect. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ederman, try {OpenCV library location}\opencv\samples\cpp\em.cpp instead of the web link. I think the sample code in the link is out of date now. I have successfully compiled the sample code in OpenCV 2.3.1. It shouldn't be a problem for 2.4.2.

Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

> **My first question is**: how can I determine the two peaks?

I would iterate through the range of sample values possible, and test when the does EM.predict(sample)[0] peaks.